# What is the difference between QQmlApplicationEngine and QQuickView?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qquickview, qqmlapplicationengine

I'm using `QQmlApplicationEngine` as follows:

```
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

app.exec();
```

But now I want to enable multisampling for my app, and `QQmlApplicationEngine` doesn't seem to have a `setFormat` method for enabling multisampling.

I found a way to do it with a `QQmlApplicationEngine` [in a forum](https://v-play.net/developers/forums/t/antialiasing#post-9745):

```
QQuickWindow* window = (QQuickWindow*) engine.rootObjects().first();
QSurfaceFormat format;
format.setSamples(16);
window->setFormat(format)
```

But it relies on the first root object of the engine being a `QQuickWindow`, which is not documented in Qt docs. So I don't want to use that technique.

Another way would be to skip `QQmlApplicationEngine` and create a `QQuickView` instead. This does have a `setFormat` method letting me enable multisampling, but I'm wondering, am I losing anything by switching from `QQmlApplicationEngine` to `QQuickView`?

In other words, what are the differences between these two classes?

One difference I found is this (from [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlapplicationengine.html#details)):

> Unlike QQuickView, QQmlApplicationEngine does not automatically create a root window. If you are using visual items from Qt Quick, you will need to place them inside of a Window.

This particular difference doesn't matter to me.

Any other differences?

Comment: Depends on what your main.qml looks like.

Comment: You don't have to assume the root object is a `QQuickWindow`, you only need a `QWindow`. You can access it with `app.topLevelWindows().first()` after loading your qml file, no need to cast or get the root object.

Comment: You will be losing convenience functionality provided from QQmlApplicationEngine and ApplicationWindow. Before it was introduced, Creator provided a QQuickView based backbone for qml apps.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Headline: QQmlApplicationEngine is newer and more powerful than QQuickView.

QQmlApplicationEngine exposes some central application functionality to QML, which QQuickView application would normally control from C++:

> - Connecting Qt.quit() to QCoreApplication::quit()
> - Automatically loads translation files from an i18n directory adjacent to the main QML file.
> - Automatically sets an incubation controller if the scene contains a QQuickWindow.
> - Automatically sets a QQmlFileSelector as the url interceptor, applying file selectors to all QML files and assets.

Ref: [Qt docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlapplicationengine.html)

At the time when QQmlApplicationEngine was introduced, the [Qt Blog had this to say](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2013/06/21/overview-of-the-new-features-in-qt-quick/):

> In Qt 5.0 we generally created Qt Quick applications by declaring a
>   QQuickView in C++ and setting the base url on it. The drawback of that
>   approach is that you have to use C++ to set properties like width,
>   height etc. In Qt 5.1 we encourage using Window or ApplicationWindow
>   as the root item of your application, giving complete control to Qt
>   Quick, so we are now introducing the QQmlApplicationEngine to make
>   this use case a little bit simpler. The QmlApplicationEngine is all
>   you need to set up your qt quick window, pick up the right translation
>   files and it implicitly connects the application quit() signal to your
>   root window.

Qt Quick Controls 2.0 is able to make use of this extra application control, through the new item [ApplicationWindow](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.7/qml-qtquick-controls2-applicationwindow.html), which:

- is similar to the regular QQuickWindow, but adds support for setting a window specific MenuBar, ToolBar and StatusBar in QML.
- makes it convenient to add a header and footer item to the window.
- makes it possible to control the window's properties, appearance and layout from QML.
- supports popups via its overlay property, which ensures that popups are displayed above other content and that the background is dimmed when a modal popup is visible.

So, in order to use some of the Qt Quick Controls features like MenuBar and Popup, we need to:

- use ApplicationWindow as our top-level QML item instead of Rectangle or Item
- use the new QQmlApplicationEngine to load the QML from C++ instead of the old QQuickView.

Answer (score 11):

You can use both together if you don't want your top level item to be a `Window`.

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
QQuickView view(&engine, 0);
// your usual engine code
view.show();
```

Comment: Above code doesn't work for me and give me:

" cannot convert argument 1 from 'QQmlApplicationEngine *' to 'QWindow *' "

Comment: right, this constructor requires two arguments, will edit